# Retry an async function that takes mutable ref as argument

Tags: rust, async-await, borrow-checker, rust-sqlx

I have a function `fetch_stuff` that needs a mutable ref to a sqlx connection. I would like to retry this function up to N times if it fails. I need this retry behavior for many similar functions so I tried to make a generic `retry_up_to_n_times` func, that takes an async fnmut and the number of retries allowed as input.

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct App {
    db_pool: sqlx::PgPool,
}

impl App {
    pub async fn foo(&self) {
        let mut db_conn = self.db_pool.acquire().await.unwrap();
        retry_up_to_n_times(|| fetch_stuff(&mut db_conn), 3).await;
    }
}

pub async fn fetch_stuff(db_conn: &mut sqlx::postgres::PgConnection) -> Result<(), StorageError> {
    //do stuff with db_conn
    Ok(())
}


pub async fn retry_up_to_n_times<F, T, O, E>(mut func: F, max_tries: usize) -> T::Output
where
    F: FnMut() -> T,
    T: std::future::Future<Output = Result<O, E>>,
    E: Error
{
    let mut fail_count = 0;
    loop {
        match func().await {
            Ok(t) => return Ok(t),
            Err(e) => {
                fail_count += 1;
                if fail_count >= max_tries {
                    return Err(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me this error

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/app/tag.rs:32:32
   |
31 |         let mut db_conn = self.db_pool.acquire().await.unwrap();
   |             ----------- variable defined here
32 |         retry_up_to_n_times(|| fetch_stuff(&mut db_conn), 3).await;
   |                              - ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------^
   |                              | |                |
   |                              | |                variable captured here
   |                              | returns an `async` block that contains a reference to a captured variable, which then escapes the closure body
   |                              inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

I don't have much experience with rust so I'm not sure I understand it fully. I've read all I could find on the subject and I tried playing with Rc and RefCell, without success.
I also tried using tokio_retry, but ended up with the same issue.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to acquire a pool connection in the closure. This is probably what you want anyway; if the connection you're using dies and this causes an error, you should get another connection on the next retry, otherwise it will be doomed to fail repeatedly since the connection is dead.

```
pub async fn foo(&self) {
    retry_up_to_n_times(
        || async {
            let mut db_conn = self.db_pool.acquire().await.unwrap();
            fetch_stuff(&mut db_conn).await
        },
        3,
    )
    .await;
}
```

(Ideally you'd return the error instead of `unwrap()`ping it, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.)

To explain why this isn't allowed, nothing about `FnMut` prevents code from calling it a second time before the first `Future` is dropped. This would cause two futures to effectively have a `&mut` to the same value, which is a violation of Rust's aliasing rules. So, a `FnMut` may not return a value that contains an exclusive borrow of a captured value.

It's a bit obscured by the async stuff in your code, but `fetch_stuff(&mut db_conn)` returns a future that contains an exclusive borrow of `db_conn`.

A simplified example illustrates the problem Rust is trying to prevent:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

fn make_two_muts<T: Display>(mut f: impl FnMut() -> T) {
    let m1 = f();
    let m2 = f();

    // Can we have two mutable references to the same value coexisting?
    format!("{m1} {m2}");
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 1;

    // No, because this isn't allowed:
    make_two_muts(move || &mut x);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, it makes more sense now, thank you ! If I understand correctly, you suggestion works since db_pool is then captured as an immutable ref, right ? What if I have a `bar` function that needs to make several `fetch_X` calls (using `retry_up_to_n_times` for each), each using the same sql transaction. There would be no way for each closure to share that transaction right ? I imagine I'd have to wrap all 3 calls in a single closure and create my transaction in it, or is there another way ?

Comment: @valentinRssl It works because each invocation of the closure creates its own connection, instead of sharing one with other invocations of the closure. You would have the same issue if you tried to share a transaction. If there is an error, ideally you should roll back the entire transaction anyway (unless you are using savepoints) and try again from the beginning.

Comment: @valentinRssl Just FYI, `RefCell` could be a way to make this work in theory, but this type doesn't maintain the reference count atomically, so it's not threadsafe and therefore isn't `Sync`, which is probably why you couldn't get it to work. You could almost certainly make it work with `Arc<Mutex<_>>` though. The runtime overhead should be minimal as there would not be any contention for the lock.